# Saying that refers to not going overboard in solving a problem when a simple solution exists

Tags: popular-refrains

So I know I've heard this saying in American English before but I just can't quite find the original.

I have come up with several made up variations like:

- I don't send the Navy (or whole army, or a battalion) when all you need is a diplomat.
- Don't buy the whole cow when all you need is milk.

What's the more commonly heard saying/phrase for this of expression?

Comment: It's not really a saying, but the word 'overengineering' immediately comes to mind.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

'Don't use a sledgehammer to crack a nut.'

To use 'a sledgehammer to crack a nut' means to use disproportionate force or expense to overcome a minor problem. ([The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/sledgehammer-to-crack-a-nut.html))

Comment: I knew I wasn't that crazy...

Comment: I wonder @Edwin Ashworth if you could tell me whether it is not too British.

Comment: If you read the PhraseFinder article, you will see that the saying originated in the States, and that all the examples they give are from the USA. You can check for more recent usage in a domain-specified (USA? UK?) Google Ngram search.

Answer (score 12):

I like

> [Don't use a cannon to kill a fly.](http://thinkexist.com/quotation/never-use-a-cannon-to-kill-a-fly/365643.html)

Answer (score 7):

- “Don’t overthink it.”
- “Don’t make a mountain out of a molehill.”
- Possibly “Don’t use grenades to kill mosquitoes.”

I’m pretty sure there are many, *many* more.

Answer (score 7):

There is an acronym *[KISS](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/KISS)*, which stands for *keep it simple, stupid* often applied to this type of situation. [*Wiktionary*]

Answer (score 3):

One example:
Don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: hmm close. But not quite what I think I heard before. I thought about that one, and felt the expression I'm looking for is more about being "excessive" or "wasteful" rather than unorthodox in solving a problem...

Comment: -1. You'd say reinventing the wheel when someone is coming up with a new method for doing something where there's an existing (and usually better) way already. That's not what OP is describing.

Answer (score 0):

In software engineering this is called ["shaving the yak"](http://sethgodin.typepad.com/seths_blog/2005/03/dont_shave_that.html). This specifically addresses the idea that the proposed solution is overly complex / will take too long, and a simpler solution would be preferable.

Comment: IME yak shaving refers more to complicated steps that are mandatory but excessive and pointless. I feel like that blog post broadens the definition to the point where it changes the meaning. Urbandict supports me on that. http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=yak%20shaving&defid=1164318