# Which adjective best describes a person who seeks complex ways of solving a simple problem?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, epithet-requests

What adjective would best describe someone who seeks complex solutions to simple problems? For example, one who would design the tree-swing in any other of the ways described below except the last one.

[image: Tree-swing problem]

Comment: What kind of description are you looking for? *Creative*, *stupid*, *complicated*, *silly*? The cartoon also doesn't necessarily imply anything other than miscommunication. We have no idea what the user *said* was wanted. Was the communication verbal? It could have been "a tree swing," completely open to interpretation, or it could have been "a tire attached to a tree branch by a rope." Or was the communication the last picture itself?

Comment: Thanks Jason, just to leave out any other factors that may be in play, you could imagine a case where you told a group of 6 guys to design a tree swing and each came up with each of the above designs. Hence, which term would describe the guys with the complex designs.

Comment: There are hundreds of possible ways to answer this. You need to be more specific as to what you're looking for.

Comment: The simple answer to your question is ***"overcomplicating"***. If you're looking for something else, then please clarify. Perhaps you're the one overcomplicating the matter.

Comment: Related: [saying that refers to not going overboard in solving a problem when a simple solution exists](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192235/saying-that-refers-to-not-going-overboard-in-solving-a-problem-when-a-simple-sol/192240#192240).

Answer (score 2):

**Rube Goldberg** / **Rube Goldberg-esque** /  **Rube Goldbergian**

> **Rube Goldberg** (adj.)

> Ingeniously or unnecessarily complicated in design or construction.
>
> *A Rube Goldberg machine* [Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=rube%20goldberg%20definition&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS911US911&oq=rube%20goldberg%20def&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j35i39j0i20i263i512j0i512j0i22i30l3j0i390.6016j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

> Accomplishing by complex means what seemingly could be done simply
>
> *A kind of Rube Goldberg contraption … with five hundred moving parts*
> [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Rube%20Goldberg)

> **Rube Goldberg**
>
> *Attributive*. Designating a device or scheme that achieves a simple
> objective by exaggeratedly or absurdly complex means; unnecessarily
> complicated, impracticable, or ingenious.
>
> **Rube Goldbergian** adj.
>
> *The oil industry provided Rube Goldbergian ice-cutting machinery that didn't work.* OED

> Linguistically speaking, a **Rube Goldberg** contraption or **Rube
> Goldbergian** or **Rube Gold-bergesque** still refers to anything
> that's overly complicated, requiring twenty-five steps to accomplish
> what could take two. [Ralph Keyes; *I Love It When You Talk Retro*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/I_Love_It_When_You_Talk_Retro/bu8cazHO9Z4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Rube%20Goldbergian%22&pg=PT238&printsec=frontcover)

Instead of using an adjective, you could also say *He's a Rube Goldberg when it comes to solving problems* to convey overcomplication. As one example below points out, Goldberg's inventions could work, at least in theory, whereas this isn't so for every idea in the the cartoon. *Rube Goldberg* addresses more your question than the cartoon's humerous "solutions."

---

> JK put a thing together from PVC pipe, some aluminum pie plates, a
> circular TV antenna, some capacitors and resistors he took from an old
> computer, and a neon light starter. It looked like a **Rube Goldberg**
> thing. [CS Moulton; *Murders Never Cease*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Murders_Never_Cease/zLWZCwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22rube%20goldberg%20thing%22&pg=PA61&printsec=frontcover)

> It is obvious that building a **Rube Goldberg** solution easily
> addresses Science and Technology standards, but this was a
> cross-curricular project that incorporated Writing standards as well.
> [D. Ambrose and R. J. Sternberg; *Creative Intelligence in the 21st
> Century*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Creative_Intelligence_in_the_21st_Centur/VmSvDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22rube%20goldberg%20solution%22&pg=PA224&printsec=frontcover)

> He would often fashion a **Rube Goldberg** solution when he wasn't
> inclined to travel to the hardware store, so I was prepared for an
> interesting solution to the leak. [T. .J. Lewis and C. L. Trempe; *The
> End of Alzheimer's*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_End_of_Alzheimer_s/kLx_DQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22rube%20goldberg%20solution%22&pg=PA395&printsec=frontcover)

> Also in the Final Destination film series the characters often die in
> **Rube Goldberg-esque** ways. In the film The Great Mouse Detective, the villain Ratigan attempts to kill the film's heroes, Basil of Baker
> Street and David Q. Dawson, with a **Rube Goldberg style device.**
> [Wikipedians (ed.); *American Comic Strips Before 1918*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/American_Comic_Strips_Before_1918/HCJpWQ8l3tcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=rube%20goldberg-esque&pg=PA149&printsec=frontcover)

> “It all *sounds* like it makes sense, but the Delta system is really a
> giant **Rube Goldberg–esque** machine,” Gleick said, gesturing out the
> window at a tangle of muddy canals. “They've twisted so many knobs and
> pulled so many levers here that no one really knows how the Delta's
> plumbing works anymore." [Alex Prud'homme; *The Ripple Effect*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Ripple_Effect/dQVPS0MFFVYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=rube%20goldberg-esque&pg=PA244&printsec=frontcover)

> So it seems that as a nation we've devoted countless resources, time,
> and energy to creating a **Rube Goldberg-esque** system of top-down
> reform while overlooking something vitally important: Do our students
> care about any of this at all? [Bryan Goodwin; *Building a Curious
> School*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Building_a_Curious_School/z1vMDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=something%20is%20rube%20goldberg-esque%20if&pg=PT51&printsec=frontcover)

> He also plans to use the gun to determine just how those **Rube
> Goldbergian** translational activators stimulate protein synthesis.
> [Ben Patrusky; "An Essential Intruder" in  *Mosaic*, Vol. 22, n.3](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Mosaic/4IeV8BMCD60C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Rube%20Goldbergian%22&pg=PA34&printsec=frontcover)

---

> Goldberg, Rube (1883–1970), US cartoonist; full name Reuben Lucius
> Goldberg. As creator of the comic strip characters Professor Lucifer
> Gorgonzola Butts (an inventor of complex mechanical devices to achieve
> simple tasks), Boob McNutt, and Lala Palooza, he satirized American
> folkways and modern technology. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/goldberg,_rube?locale=en)

Answer (score 1):

In British English, **Heath Robinson** is more common:

> *Heath Robinson* [adjective] [British]
>
> Ingeniously or ridiculously over-complicated in design or
> construction.

> [(1872–1944), English cartoonist and illustrator; full name William
> Heath Robinson. He lampooned the machine age by inventing absurdly
> complicated ‘Heath Robinson contraptions’ to perform elementary or
> ridiculous actions.]

- *His was a Heath Robinson approach to fixing everything*

[[The Sunday Times; 2005](https://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/were-all-british-innit-ql68tjrmt6b)]